# Cheap & Effective Way to Soundproof Windows

Tags: doors, windows, sound-proofing

I am looking to soundproof my home from the busy road that is in front of it. The roads are concrete not asphalt so the tires make a substantial amount of noise since the speed limit is 40mph.

I have listened carefully as to where the sound is coming from and it is mostly caused by the door and the windows. I purchased some of the weather stripping foam which helped some but not enough.

I was wondering if there is a mainstream version of a transparent audio barrier that can be placed over the window? I know that there is a trademarked company "AudioSeal" but I tried finding them on Amazon.com and some other .com companies and was not able to find them. Let me know what you guys think or if this is even worth while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options you could consider depending on your budget and opinion on "cheap".  There are acoustic dampening windows you could look into if you have a higher budget and don't mind replacing your window.  If you're sure that the main source of noise penetration is through the window, which is to be expected, then this might be the best / most permanent route.  The AudioSeal looks pretty promising, and there are some more cheaper options.  A simple search for 'Transparent Vinyl Barrier' gives you a lot of relevant results.  The quality and the transparency of the product will depend on your budget.  Curtains, and specifically acoustic cancelling curtains might be your best bet, but they can be pricey (and very cheap, technically you could use your bedsheets as curtains, although they wouldn't help much).

Here are some relevant links you might want to check out:

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/block-out-noise-coming-through-window-31141.html

and

http://removeandreplace.com/2014/12/02/how-to-soundproof-a-window-and-block-noise/

Good luck!

Comment: We are getting new windows in the near future which in and of themselves would probably help some but I am thinking that the "dampening" windows is probably the most promising. I need to speak with the guy that is going to do our windows to see what he thinks. Honestly I was just hoping for a quick easy way to lessen the noise so I can sleep at night haha. the keyword in the search is vinyl. I wasn't using that in my search.

Comment: Glad I could help (sort of), make sure to mark it as the answer if you think it is ;)