# How can I conveniently soundproof a bedroom window?

Tags: sound-proofing, bedroom, noise-reduction, sound-deadening

Does anyone have an inexpensive way to “soundproof” a bedroom window that doesn’t require lots of installation? I’ve read about different techniques like acoustic foam/panels/blankets, but some people say this doesn’t work.

I have an ear injury that I’m afraid will worsen from sound, so I’m unable to drill holes or do any install.

I thought about gluing some acoustic foam pieces together to fit the size of my window, but I’m overwhelmed with choices on foam and which ones to choose. I’m also not sure if it will work. Are the materials in the foam safe to breathe in and/or cut to size? If anyone has links to specific products, I would be extremely grateful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce noise coming in a window for under $100?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/262354/how-can-i-reduce-freeway-noise-coming-in-a-window-for-under-100)

Comment: Or this? [What could I do to reduce noise through a bedroom window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183835/double-glazed-windows-reduce-only-part-of-noise-what-could-i-do-next)

Comment: Or this? [Cheap & Effective Way to Soundproof Windows](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93164/cheap-effective-way-to-soundproof-windows)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Only ask one question per post.